# what is the best way to have multivalue fields in template?

Tags: templates

I've a template name "teacher". Teacher template has following fields :
- Name
- Designation
- DateOfJoin
- Social

Where social field should capture following data:
- Type (FB/Twitter/Instagram)
- Link
- Icon

what should be the datatype of "Social" field so that we can add multiple social links.  Can somebody suggest me the best approch to achieve this.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good option for this would be to use Sub Items (children) to store the Social data.

So you would create a new template with fields as @nathanhase mentioned, e.g.

`SocialLink` with fields:
* **SocialType** - Droplink pointing at a set of lookup items to define the type, e.g. Twitter, Facebook etc...
* **SocialLink** - General Link field
* **SocialIcon** - Image field

Then you would create sub items of your `Teacher` data item for each social account the teacher has.

This would work, but if you wanted to make it easier for content editors, you could use the **[Express Sub Item](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Express_Subitem.aspx)** module from the market place. This module enables editing of child items from the parent.
You would get this type of effect (screen shots are pre sc8, but sc8.2 is supported):

[image: Collapsed]

[image: Expanded]

This meets all your requirements mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do would be to split that into three fields on your Teacher template. It would also be reasonable to have these three fields in a separate "Social" section of the template.

**SocialType** - Droplink field with a source pointing at a folder with simple Items that have names which will be set as the value of the field.

**SocialLink** - General Link field

**SocialIcon** - Image field with a source pointing at a media folder that contains the available icons.

These can be collected into an object within the Model that uses this data, if necesary.

**Multiple social networks**

Create a General Link field for each of the possible social networks. You'll know which network by the name of the field. Icons are generally a consistent application via css so those don't need to be selected in Sitecore.

Comment: in that case i won't be able to add multiple social links like fb, instagram & twitter.

Comment: No, but your question doesn't say that you need to do that either.
You can spread these out as a set of fields for each social media network. It can be a single link field in that case. The icon tends to be consistent for each network, not something that is selected by authors..

Comment: I've updated the question. Thanks for pointing out this.